# ARR IIS got 503 Service Unavailable every morning of the day

Tags: .net, iis, load-balancing, arr

I use **ARR** feature on **IIS** to implement the load balancing web application. I have 2 **ARR Servers**, 2 **Web Servers**. Every day, on the first time when user accesses the page, he always get the *503 Service Unavailable* error. After he pressed F5 key to reload the page a few times, the website started working properly again.

Please help me to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be possible that the App pool resources got free while the site has no requests for a specific amount of time.

In that case, when users send requests to the site then it needs some time for warm-up and after that, you could notice that the site works fine.

To avoid this issue, you could try to go to the `IIS-> App pools -> Select your site app pool -> go to Advanced settings`.

Set **Start mode** as **Always running**.

[image]

See whether it helps to fix the said issue.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. I will apply your suggestion and let you know the result.

Comment: @Rango  I would like to know whether the suggestion I provide you helped you fix the above-mentioned issue? Please inform us of the current status of the issue.

Comment: I don't see the error after setting Start Mode to AlwaysRunning. Thank you for your suggestion.